# Custom property in user profile service application does not exists in SharePoint 2013 my site

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I configured UP service application in SharePoint 2013 CA successfully and every thing works good. But I have a problem and that is when I create some new custom properties in UP, after start synchronizing, those custom properties don't exist in my site yet.
please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have done similar steps to to you for a client

Here are there steps I went though
- decide which properties you want to map to in AD (user class) add if you want new ones
- update these properties via a PS script or external systems. In my case I used an .CSV file which I gave to the business for them to update the appropriate columns
- Go into you the User properties editor in CA -> UPA  but ensure you create your mappings to AD properties as well - choose import from AD 
- check your connection and also the 2 ( evil !!!) FIM Services are up and are not on strike!
- check you are using User profile sync and not the light weight Active Directory Import
- in my sites profiles check the last eplipse which as a menu for custom attributes.  I have an  issue whereby only one of the two new ones are being displayed....